# Apache .htaccess Subfolder access only one one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I've got the following problem:

I have two domains which vhost is pointing on the same directory (Magento Multishop Instance). Lets say its domain-a.com and domain-b.com.

Inside the document root is a blog directory which should only be accessible from domain-a.com via /blog.

Now my question is how can I prohibit the access to this sub directory from domain-b.com.

Thanks in advance
bambamboole

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved by having the virtual host for domain-a contain `<Directory "/blog"> Require all granted </Directory>` while the vhost for domain-b should contain `<Directory "/blog"> Require all denied </Directory>`. If it's pre apache 2.3.9, you'll also want to add `AllowOverride None` within the directory tags but on a separate line below `Require all denied`.

You can find more information in the [apache.org docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)